# prevState not consistent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to add `thumbnail` URL into my thumbnail state array. But also to prevent an infinite loop I am trying to compare the previous state from the current state. However, when doing so the previous state keeps referring back to the state object? The array that I need is the one that shows Explore line 35. And ideally I thought that would be the current State, since that is what it is printing.

[image]

**Constructor**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.getVideos();
    this.state = {
      thumbnail: []
    };
  }
```

**ComponentDidUpdate**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    console.log("Current State->" + this.state.thumbnail);
    console.log("Previous State->" + JSON.stringify(prevState.videos));
    // console.log("Previous State->" + prevState.videos.video);
    if (this.props.videos == null) {
      console.log("It's null");
    } else {
      if (this.state !== prevState) {
        const videos = this.props.videos.video.map(video => {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            thumbnail: prevState.thumbnail.concat(video.thumbnail)
          }));
          console.log(this.state.thumbnail);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Reducers snippet**

```
case GET_VIDEOS:
  return {
    ...state,
    videos: action.payload,
    loading: false
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Few issues that I can see right away:

1. `if (this.state !== prevState)` is not a valid way of comparing the old state to the new. They are just comparing their references as variables (which will always be different) - not their contents. To do this properly you need to compare each state variable one-by-one. Either use a library for that, such as lodash's `_isEqual` or implement your own solution (good idea if your state is small).
2. Doing `console.log(this.state.thumbnail);` right after your `setState()` will actually print the previous value because `setState()` is asynchronous. Instead, put your log inside the callback parameter of `setState()`:

   ```
   this.setState(prevState => ({
     thumbnail: prevState.thumbnail.concat(video.thumbnail)
   }), () => console.log(this.state.thumbnail));
   ```

Comment: That makes sense. But why is my current state not even stored in an array per the console? It doesnt make sense that it just prints not inside of an array and then it is in an array. Something better to ask is how can I simply just add data into my state array?

Comment: @The_Enigma can you elaborate? Which part of the output specifically are you referring to?